# Justification of interchanging limit and integral in the proof of the derivative of Cauchy integral formula

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, limits, cauchy-integral-formula

On Stein and Shakarchi's Complex Analysis book, in the course of proving that for $f$ a holomorphic (i.e. differentiable) function on an open set, and $C$ a circle whose interior is also contained in the domain of $f$, $$f^{(n)} = \frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}d\zeta$$
by induction on $n$, the author makes the following assertion: if we let $A=\frac{1}{\zeta-z-h}, B = \frac{1}{\zeta-z}$ we have that $$\frac{f^{(n-1)}(z+h)-f^{(n-1)}(z)}{h} = \frac{(n-1)!}{2\pi i}\int_C \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z-h)(\zeta-z)}(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B+...+B^{n-1}) d\zeta.$$

I get everything until this point. However, I do not get why the following claim by the author implies that I can interchange limit and integral: "**but observe that if $h$ is small, then $z+h$ and $z$ stay at a finite distance from the boundary circle $C$, so in the limit as $h \to 0$, we find that the quotient converges to $$\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}d\zeta.$$**

I know that we can interchange the limit and integral if the limit is uniform. However, it seems very complicated to determine that the integrand $g_m :=\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z-h_m)(\zeta-z)}(A^{n-1}+A^{n-2}B+...+B^{n-1})$ converges uniformly to $g :=\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}$ as $m \to \infty$ directly from the definition of uniform convergence. (Here, $\{h_m\}$ is an arbitrary sequence approaching $0$. The $h$'s in the definition of $A$ is also subtituted by $h_m$ in the definition of $g_m$.) How can the author so quickly justify the switching of the integral and the limit?

Comment: I think Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem clearly suffices.

Comment: Thanks, I am wondering if we can use uniform convergence criterion, especially due to the author's comments I boldfaced.

Comment: I believe this issue is discussed in Tristan Needham's Visual Complex analysis in an intuitive way in the chapter where he discusses power series. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: You can probably obtain uniform convergence from a complex mean value inequality as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208609/mean-value-theorem-for-complex-functions

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3750161/121671) are some solutions that use dominated convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $g : C \times C^c \to \mathbb{C}$ by
$$g(\zeta, z) = \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n}}.$$
Let $g_z : C \times C^c \to \mathbb{C}$ denote the derivative of $g$ wrt $z$. Fix $z \in C^c$. You want to prove that $$\sup_{\zeta \in C}|\frac{g(\zeta, z + h) - g(\zeta, z)}{h} - g_z(\zeta, z)| \to 0 \text{ as } h \to 0.$$
By the FTC, for $\zeta \in C$, and $|h| < r := \text{dist}(z, C)$,
$$\frac{g(\zeta, z + h) - g(\zeta, z)}{h} = \int_{0}^{1}g_z(\zeta, z + th)\,dt.$$
Hence for $\zeta \in C$ and $|h| < r$,
\begin{align}
|\frac{g(\zeta, z + h) - g(\zeta, z)}{h} - g_z(\zeta, z)| &= |\int_{0}^{1}(g_z(\zeta, z + th) - g_z(\zeta, z))\,dt| \\
&\leq \int_{0}^{1}|g_z(\zeta, z + th) - g_z(\zeta, z)|\,dt \\
&\leq \sup_{z_1 \in D_{|h|}(z)}|g_z(\zeta, z_1) - g_z(\zeta, z)| \\
&\leq \omega_{g_z, C \times \overline{D_{|h|}(z)}}(|h|),
\end{align}
where $\omega_{g_z, C \times \overline{D_{|h|}(z)}}$ is a modulus of continuity for the uniformly continuous function $g_z$ on $C \times \overline{D_{|h|}(z)}$. $g_z$ is indeed uniformly continuous on $C \times \overline{D_{|h|}(z)}$ because $g_z$ is continuous on $C \times C^c$, and $C \times \overline{D_{|h|}(z)}$ is compact. For $|h| < r/2$,
$$\omega_{g_z, C \times \overline{D_{|h|}(z)}}(|h|) \leq \omega_{g_z, C \times \overline{D_{r/2}(z)}}(|h|) \to 0 \text{ as } h \to 0.$$
This completes the proof.

Edit: Here are some details on "modulus of continuity". I like to think of the "canonical" modulus of continuity of a function $f : X \to Y$ between two metric spaces as the map $\omega : [0, \infty) \to [0, \infty]$ defined by
$$\omega(\delta) = \sup_{d(x_1, x_2) \leq \delta}d(f(x_1), f(x_2)).$$
Note that $d(x_1, x_2) \leq \delta \implies d(f(x_1), f(x_2)) \leq \omega(\delta)$. It is easy to show that $f$ is uniformly continuous if and only if $\omega(\delta) \searrow 0$ as $\delta \searrow 0$.

For this problem, we don't need to compute the modulus of continuity explicitly, i.e. we don't need hard quantitative estimates on it. For this problem, all was needed was that $g_z$ was continuous so that we could conclude that it's modulus of continuity has the limit $0$ at $0$.

Comment: @CuteBrownie I added details to my answer. You can try to compute the "canonical" modulus of continuity I defined in the edit to my answer, but it isn't necessary for this problem. All we needed for this problem is that it has the limit $0$ at $0$.