# Dirac delta as a limit of sequence of functions

Tags: calculus, distribution-theory, sequence-of-function

I have problem to proof that dirac delta function can be represented as following limits:
$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{\varepsilon}{\pi(x^2+\varepsilon^2)}=\delta(x) $$
$$ \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\frac{1}{\varepsilon\sqrt{\pi}}\text{exp}\Big(\frac{-x^2}{\varepsilon^2}\Big)=\delta(x) $$
I have intuition why this is true, but I don't know how to solve it analytically. I tried to put theese expretions under integral with some trial functions to check if:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x) dx= g(0),$$
where $f_\varepsilon$ is one of above sequence of functions and $g(x)$ is this trial function. This should hold by definition of Dirac delta: limit of some sequence of function with property that $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)\cdot g(x)dx = g(0)$. Checking this definition property should proof the convergence to Dirac delta, but I don't know how to compute such integrals (generality of trial function is quite problematic).

Comment: What are the assumptions on $g$? (Continuous? Differentiable? square-integrable?) What integration do you use? (Riemann-integration?) I think your best bet would be using the definition of integral.

Comment: Well I'm using dirac delta in quantum mechanics course in my university so I suppose it is reasonable to assume g is square-integrable and differentiable. Also I suppose to have more generality it will be better to use lebesque integration (not even sure if dirac delta is riemann integrable).

Comment: I think the only important property of $g$ here is it's continuous at $0$. The Dirac delta is not Riemann integrable or Lebesgue integrable since it's not a function at all, just a "generalized function". $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0} f_\epsilon(x)$ does not exist at $x=0$ and is $0$ everywhere else. But rather than the integral of the limit, you can prove the limit of the integral has the wanted property, and that's the key point of the Dirac delta.

Comment: @aschepler with e.g. $g(x)=e^{x^4}$ none of the integrals would converge for any value of $\varepsilon>0$, so _some_ integration conditions on $g$ are necessary.

Comment: @student91 Good point. I think my proof idea would actually require that $g$ is bounded almost everywhere ($g \in L^\infty$).

Comment: Will it be sufficient to check that for $x = 0$ both sequences have limits plus infinity, and for $x \neq 0$ they are convergent to $0$? Because I know how to do it, and I know that the Dirac delta behave that way, but I don't know how it is associated with the definition that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)\cdot g(x)dx = g(0)$

Comment: Make a variable change in the integral: $x = \varepsilon y.$

Comment: I want to point out that your definition is wrong. You’re supposed to show $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}f_{\epsilon}g=g(0)$. It is very important the limit is outside.. The fancy terminology is that $\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to 0^+}f_{\epsilon}=\delta_0$ **in the weak* topology on the space of distributions**, this is **NOT** a pointwise limit. Anyway, I’ve provided a general statement and proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4216448/568204).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $g\in C_C^\infty$.  Then, enforcing the substituion $x\mapsto \varepsilon x$ and appealing to the Dominated Convergence Theorem yields

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\varepsilon}{\pi(x^2+\varepsilon^2)}g(x)\,dx&\overbrace{=}^{x\mapsto \varepsilon x}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{\pi(x^2+1)}g(\varepsilon x)\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{DCT}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left(\frac1{\pi(x^2+1)}g(\varepsilon x)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=g(0)
\end{align}$$

Similarly, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac1{\varepsilon\sqrt\pi}e^{-x^2/\varepsilon^2}g(x)\,dx&\overbrace{=}^{x\mapsto \varepsilon x}\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac1{\sqrt \pi}e^{-x^2}g(\varepsilon x)\,dx\\\\
&\overbrace{=}^{\text{DCT}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}\left(\frac1{\sqrt \pi}e^{-x^2}g(\varepsilon x)\right)\,dx\\\\
&=g(0)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, in distribution we have

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \frac{\varepsilon}{\pi(x^2+\varepsilon^2)}=\delta(x)$$

and

$$\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \frac1{\varepsilon \sqrt \pi}e^{-x^2/\varepsilon^2}=\delta(x)$$

as was to be shown!

Comment: It should be $g(\epsilon x)$ for all these equations, no?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ugh!  Of course.  Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but I'm not sure how DCT works in this case. As I read the theorem says about convergence of sequence to measurable function. So how it allows you to put this limit inside integral?

Comment: @XaveryXavier [THIS POST](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168778/dominated-convergence-theorem-what-sequence/3168802#3168802) should answer your question.

Comment: @MarkViola just curious (clearly your answer is better, you got my +1), where did I use DCT? It is not needed for steps 1,3 or 4 and how step 2 is solved depends on the criteria on $g$, so I guess you mean I do so in step 2? Or do you mean in the part after the 4 steps?

Comment: @student91 Well, you referenced a solution posted by peek-a-boo for another answer.  In that post, the DCT was used to justify bringing the limit inside the integral.

Comment: ah yes, that post didn't use DCT when I edited to that post in.

Comment: @student91 It actually did.  Look at the "long-winded" solution before the recent edit.  That said, the DCT is not required.  But it does make things easy.

Answer (score 2):

> Will it be sufficient to check that for $x=0$ both sequences have limits plus infinity, and for $x\neq 0$ they are convergent to $0$? Because I know how to do it, and I know that the Dirac delta behave that way, but I don't know how it is associated with the definition that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\delta(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x=g(0)$.

No, this is not sufficient. A proof would go along the following lines:

1. Note that for any $e>0$ we have that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^{-e} f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_{-e}^e f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_e^\infty f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x$
2. Note that for sufficiently small values of $\varepsilon$ (esp. small with respect to $e$) we have that $\int_{-\infty}^{-e} f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x+\int_e^\infty f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is *small* (for which one needs integration criteria on $g$ and bounds on $f_\varepsilon$ away from $0$).
3. Note that by continuity of $g$ we can take $\min_{x\in[-e,e]}g(x)$ and $\mathrm{max}_{x\in[-e,e]}g(x)$ arbitrarily close to $g(0)$ by choosing $e$ sufficiently small.
4. Note that for sufficiently small $\varepsilon$ we have that $\int_{-e}^e f_\varepsilon(x)\mathrm{d}x$ is arbitrarily close to $1$

For a formal proof similar to this, take a look at [peek-a-boo's link in the comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4208501/diracs-delta-distribution-smooth-approximation/4216448).

In this fashion, we can obtain: $$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x = \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{(-\infty,-e)\cup(e,\infty)} f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x + \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{-e}^e f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x$$$$\leq 0+\left(\mathrm{max}_{x\in[-e,e]}g(x)\right)\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{-e}^e f_\varepsilon(x)\mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{max}_{x\in[-e,e]}g(x)$$

And similarly we have $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x\geq\min_{x\in[-e,e]}g(x)$.

We have thus found $$\min_{x\in[-e,e]}g(x)\leq\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d} x\leq\mathrm{max}_{x\in[-e,e]} g(x)$$ for any $e$. This can only hold for *any* $e$ (by continuity of $g$) if this is equal to $g(0)$.

The tricky part here is proving 2, for which we need some assumptions on the behaviour of $g$. Part 4. is also not that straightforward to do, but the comment by md2perpe will help you for that.

Comment: by the way, I’ve given a full proof in my answer to [Dirac's $\delta$
 distribution smooth approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4216448/568204).

Comment: Thank you, that's a nice read! Note that in this case, we have that $\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_\varepsilon(x)\cdot g(x)\mathrm{d}x=0$ for an even broader class of functions than $g\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. e.g. for the $f_\varepsilon(x)=\frac1{\varepsilon\sqrt\pi}e^{-(\frac x\varepsilon)^2}$ case you can even take $g$ to be polynomials of arbitrary degree (And polynomials do sometimes appear in these kind of situations in my experience), and you can still make this proof work.

Comment: Just curious.  Why go through the trouble of splitting the integral when clearly the substitution $x\mapsto \varepsilon x$ at the start along with application of the DCT works?  See my posted solution herein.