# Dirac delta function as a limit of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, dirac-delta

For some nice function $f(x)$, how to show the following using contour integration?
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2} dx = \pi f(0)
$$

The way I would approach this integral is by $\frac{d}{dx} \tan^{-1} \frac{x}{\epsilon} = \frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon^2+x^2}$ and integrating by parts. This assumes $f$ does not increase too quickly, as for example when $f(x)=x$, the integral on the LHS does not converge.

I'm hoping to see a method that can be extended to an integral of the form
$$
\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \frac{\epsilon}{(\epsilon^2+x^2)(x^2 - (\omega+i\epsilon)^2)} dx
$$

where $f$ has some poles in the complex plane.

Also found a similar question here: [Dirac delta as a limit of sequence of functions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4642800/dirac-delta-as-a-limit-of-sequence-of-functions)

Comment: I would change the variable $x=\epsilon u$ and with the right niceness assumptions on $f$, apply the Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem.

Comment: Just realized this is the same as the answer that you linked in your post.

Comment: Also, I think there's a sign error. If you replace $f$ by the constant function $1$, you should get $\pi$ in the right-hand side. Or another way to see it, is that if $f$ is positive almost everywhere, so should the right-hand side be.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the typo

Comment: To do this by contour integration, you'd have to assume $f$ is analytic over either the entire upper or lower half-plane, and that $\frac {f(z)}z \to 0$ as $z \to \infty$. This is far too limited a set of functions for such a proof to be worthwhile.